# R.java auto generation problem

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to implement MJAndroid. There R.java is getting generated on its own. I want to delete the auto generated one and either create my own or overwrite the existing one. Its not allowing me to do so. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> There R.java is getting generated on its own. I want to delete the auto generated one and either create my own or overwrite the existing one. Its not allowing me to do so.

AFAIK, that is not possible. Whatever problem you think you are solving this way can hopefully be solved in some other way.